# complementery of an if case

Tags: ios, swift, if-case

How would you write this:

```
if case .SomeEnum(3) = enumType where myInt == 3 {
   //I don't need this case
} else {
   //This is the case I need
}
```

I know I could use `guard`:

```
guard case .SomeEnum(3) = enumType where myInt == 3 else {
    //This is the case I need
}
```

but I don't think it is clean, since it is not really a case in which the function is not able to finish. Also, `guard` expects me to return from the function.

Any other alternatives?

Comment: Couldn't it just be `if .SomeEnum != enumType || myInt != 3`?

Comment: `.SomeEnum != enumType` or `.SomeEnum == enumType` gives compiler errors, since the enums have parameters

Comment: Oh I see. Good question :)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you *cannot* negate a pattern. I would consider your first solution as the best one, alternatively a switch statement with one case plus the `default` case. – You *can* use guard with a local scope, but that would be more like obfuscating Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot negate a pattern (as far as I know), and your first solution
using `if/else` looks fine to me, the intention of the code is clearly
visible.

A switch statement would be an alternative:

```
switch enumType {
case .SomeEnum(3) where myInt == 3:
    break  // I don't need this case
default:
    // This is the case I need
    // ...
}
```

With regard to your remark

> Also, guard expects me to return from the function.

that is not entirely true. You are expected to leave the current scope.
So this would compile and work as expected:

```
repeat {
    guard case .SomeEnum(3) = enumType where myInt == 3 else {
        // This is the case I need
        // ...
        break
    }
} while false
```

but I would not consider that a better solution.

Comment: I had the same idea using `switch`, the *don't need* pattern is `case .SomeEnum(let value) where value == 3 && value == myInt:` or maybe even simply `case .SomeEnum(let value) where value == myInt:`

Comment: @vadian: `case .SomeEnum(3) where myInt == 3:` would be the same pattern as in the question.

Comment: @vadian: `case .SomeEnum(let value) where value == myInt:` (if that is what OP actually meant) can be shortened to `case .SomeEnum(myInt):`

Comment: You can use `do { ... }` instead of `repeat { ... } while false`.

Comment: @NobodyNada: Yes, but – unless I am overlooking something – you can break out of it only if you give it a label: `LABEL: do { ... }` and `break LABEL`.