# Pattern matching negation

Tags: swift, pattern-matching

How can I negate pattern matching in Swift?

For example I want to do something like:

```
guard case .wait != currentAction.type else {
    return
}
```

But apparently, I can't. I can do this:

```
    if case .wait = currentAction.type {
        return
    }
```

but it's less Swifty. Is there a better way?

Comment: You cannot negate a pattern, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926509/complementery-of-an-if-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is no way to do that right now as of Swift 3.

Things can change in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Swift 3.0.2:

```
guard currentAction.type != .wait else {
    return
}
```